# How to count occurrences from a dictionary in a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, count, python-requests

After researching similar questions, I was not able to find a definite answer as to how this is done or if it even can be done. I am trying to count the number of occurrences in an output that are in my dictionary.

Code:

```
server_owners_dict=dict()

    for i in data['resources']:
            if 'id' in i and 'name' in i:
                b = i['name'], i['id']
                k = str(b)
                if  re.findall("'Server-Ownership-\w+', \w+", k):
                    matchedOwners = re.findall("'Server-Ownership-\w+', \w+", k)[0]
                    j = str(matchedOwners).strip().split() 
                    server_owners_dict[j[0].replace('Server-Ownership-','')]=j[1]


    with open(PATH, mode='w') as my_csv_file:
        employee_writer = csv.writer(my_csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        employee_writer.writerow(['Server Name','Criticals'])
        for owner in server_owners_dict:
            url = server + "/api/3/asset_groups/" + str(server_owners_dict[owner]) + "/assets"
            response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify=False, params = {owner:server_owners_dict[owner]})
            data = response.json()
            for i in data['resources']:
                url = server+ "/api/3/assets/" + str(i)
                response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify=False)
                data = response.json()
                if data['vulnerabilities']['critical'] > 0:
                    d = (owner)
```

The output of d looks like this:

```
'Bob',
'Bob',
'Bob',
'Jeff',
'Jeff',
'Mary',
```

These are the 'owners' in my dictionary and I would like to count the times they occur in this output and then return something like this:

```
Bob: 3
Jeff: 2
Mary: 1
```

I tried setting "owners=[]" before my for loop and then doing "owner +=1"
after the if statement at the bottom, but it kept saying it is not iterable.

Comment: you appear to have a rogue `"` here: `with open(PATH"`

Comment: @Nullman i have the actual path in my script i just set it to PATH here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list like:

```
Bob
Bob
Bob
Jeff
Jeff
Mary
```

Which probably means something along the lines of

`d = ["Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Jeff", "Jeff", "Mary"]`

Then you can simply do

```
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter(d)
```

And you'll have

`Counter({'Bob': 3, 'Jeff': 2, 'Mary': 1})`

Comment: this counts the individual words for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Counter* module. I don't quite understand all of your code, but it is a trivial problem with this module and having all the occurrences in a list:

```
from collections import Counter

# you can construct this array while looping if it isn't done yet
occurrences = ['Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Jeff', 'Jeff', 'Mary']
Counter(occurrences) # this returns a dict with keys and number of occurences
>>> Counter({'Bob': 3, 'Jeff': 2, 'Mary': 1})
```

Comment: the beginning of my code looks through a JSON output to find a particular string that has the owner names associated with it. thats why i used "re.findall". I cannot hard code the owners as this can change at any time.

Comment: You could try to initialize an empty array at the beginning of the code and populate it each time you find an owner, something _like your_list = []_ and then _your_list .append(owner)_ (may need proper format according to your code and variables names)

Comment: this may work. whenever i try printing the list at the end of the if statement, it makes a new list for every occurrence it finds. am i possibly placing the print statement in the wrong place?

Comment: Put the empty list at the top of your code, so it gets created only once.

Comment: i did and it still creates a new list for every occurrence it finds

Comment: Right after _server_owners_dict=dict()_? And then _list.append(owner)_ right after _d = (owner)_

Comment: thats exactly how i have it and every time it finds an owner it will make a new line with the occurrence added. So basically it makes a new line that is one result longer than the one before it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208429/discussion-between-pythonscrub-and-jcf).